# How to adjust Google Charts (WordTree) to take data source from Google sheets URL?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I want to get WordTree created from Google sheets URL as a data source

The wordTree chart is at:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree

and changing Datasource can be found
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts

However I'm keep getting errors and can't grab the sheet and code doesn't run

Comment: Looking to replace this section:
 function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          [ ['Phrases'],
            ['cats are better than dogs'],
            ['cats eat kibble'],
            ['cats are better than hamsters'],
            ['cats are better than kittens'],
            ['cats are evil'],
            ['cats are weird'],
            ['cats eat mice'],
          ]
        );
to a line that takes the data from google sheets instead
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loB8SHnERMVCyjaWWkWi-ADmA99Yjf4FrgGD-oPUPdA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to work with the chart wrapper class...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['wordtree']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'WordTree',
    containerId: 'chart',
    dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loB8SHnERMVCyjaWWkWi-ADmA99Yjf4FrgGD-oPUPdA/edit?usp=sharing',
    query: 'SELECT A,B',
    options: {
      wordtree: {
        format: 'implicit',
        word: 'patio'
      }
    }
  });
  chart.draw();
});
```

be sure the `query` property is set to pull the columns with data.

see following fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/L0vmk2tq/

Comment: Appreciate your answer
Is it possible to switch to codepen?
jsfiddle is blocked in China, and I can't access it even with US VPN

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/WhiteHat1999/pen/NWjjNYb)...